# Очистка списка

Tags: c++

Как очистить заполненный список в С++? Вот создал пустой класс. Начинаю заполнять его определенной функцией, а теперь надо его обнулить? Поможете с функцией? Вот сам класс:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct element {
    string data;
    element *adress;
};

class List {
  private:
    element * StartAdress, *FinishAdress;

  public:
    List() {
        StartAdress = NULL;
        FinishAdress = NULL;
    } void ElAdd(string a) {
        element *e;
        e = new element;
        e->data = a;

        if (StartAdress == NULL) {
            StartAdress = e;
        } else {
            FinishAdress->adress = e;
        }

        FinishAdress = e;
        FinishAdress->adress = NULL;
    }

    void print() {
        element *e;
        for (e = StartAdress; e != NULL; e = e->adress)
            cout << e->data << " " << endl;
    }
};
```

Сам вот подумал что так:

```
void ElDel (string a)
{
     StartAdress == NULL;
     FinishAdress == NULL;
}
```

Но кажется, не сработало. Подскажете?

Comment: Правильно. Мусор за собой надо убирать.

Comment: Т.е. все удалять по одному? А все сразу нельзя сделать?

Comment: Нет. Вы же сами и пишете функцию, которая очищает список. 

--

Только вот задуманная Вами void ElDel (string a) это что-то другое. Видимо это функция в некотором смысле обратная к void ElAdd (string a). И она должна удалить из списка элемент (или все элементы ?) у которого(ых) data равно a.

Как-то так ?

Comment: @avp да, извиняюсь. Название функции не то вышло. Мне надо очистить просто весь список! Поэтому вот я подумал, что если присвоить к начальеому и конечному значению NULL, тогда обнулю его. Но кажется что-то не так

Comment: Так вы не присвоили, а сравнили на равенство. Но просто присваивать 0 все равно нельзя.

Comment: @navi1893, дело не в названии. Зачем функции, очищающей **весь** список нужен аргумент ?!!!

Как надо делать, @Данил Вам написал.

--

Преобразовал его комментарий в ответ, но так теперь с остальными комментариями получилось кривовато. Извиняюсь.

Comment: а на примере нельзя показать? так сложновато мне как то понять

Comment: А Вы попробуйте. Начните с while(StartAdress != NULL) { ...

Идея та же, что и в Вашей void print().

Comment: @navi1893 Если у вас система со сборкой мусора, то можно. Если нет, то нет. Т.е. удалить можно, но использовать эту память уже нельзя. Возникает утечка памяти (memory leak). Для C++ есть какие-то проекты с garbage collector, но подробностей я не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Перебираем все объекты начиная с StartAdress. Запоминаем во временную переменную адрес объекта StartAdress, передвигаем указатель StartAdress на слудеющий элемент и делаем delete для временной переменной. И так пока список не закончится.